# Require associatedtype to be representable in a @convention(c) block

Tags: swift

I want to have a generic way of doing something like in Swift 3:

```
public protocol Callable {
    associatedtype In : CVarArg
    associatedtype Out : CVarArg
}

public struct IntCallable : Callable {
    public typealias In = Int
    public typealias Out = Double

    public typealias FunctionalBlock = @convention(c) (In) -> Out

    public func call(_ block: FunctionalBlock) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

So I'd like it to look more like this:

```
public protocol Callable {
    associatedtype In : CVarArg
    associatedtype Out : CVarArg
    typealias FunctionalBlock = @convention(c) (In) -> Out
}

public struct IntCallable : Callable {
    public typealias In = Int
    public typealias Out = Double
}

public extension Callable {
    public func call(_ block: FunctionalBlock) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
'(Self.In) -> Self.Out' is not representable in Objective-C, so it cannot be used with '@convention(c)'
```

Is there any constraint I can place on the In/Out associatedtypes that will allow my to declare the generic form of the FunctionalBlock? It works fine without `@convention(c)`, but I need it in order to form a C function call.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in Swift, due to the how Swift manages values passed as protocols, and `CVarArg` is a protocol.

What happens behind the scenes is that when passing a value under the umbrella of a protocol, the Swift compiler creates an existential container that wraps the value, a value which is transparently unwrapped at the callee site.

So basically your block actually looks something like this:

```swift
typealias FunctionalBlock = @convention(c) (Container<In>) -> Container<Out>
```

Due to this behind-the-scenes transform, you're not passing values that can be represented in C, thus the error you get.

This is very similar to other protocol related issues, like the famous [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

Your best bet would be to add overloads for all types that conform to CVarArg, since this is a finite and unchangeable list.