# Does swift have a "C Type" protocol?

Tags: swift

I would like to constrain a generic to a type that can be represented in C.  Is there a protocol or type in the Swift standard library that all C types conform to?

```
func doWithCType<T:CRepresentable>(cValue: T) {
    // do thing with C type
}
```

If not a CRepresentable, maybe a CStruct type?

**Clues:**

Using this C type:

```
typedef struct {
    int hodor;
} Hodor;
```

I force casted a struct to an incompatible type (causing a crash). This was the error message: `Could not cast value of type '__C.Hodor' (0x1035c0700) to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x107196240).`

I can't find "__C" anywhere, but I'm hopeful that there's a distinction for the C types.

Comment: What do you consider "a type representable in C"? Anything can be represented in C as raw memory... Plain datatypes?

Comment: A c type like a struct or an int that can be accepted as an argument to a C function.  I’m hoping to avoid the void* route.

Comment: I’m trying to make a Swift/C message queue.

Comment: There's no such native protocol in Swift — you'd have to create it yourself. What are you trying to do here though? Once you have something constrained to `CRepresentable`, how do you intend to pass it to C anyway? C can't currently call Swift, but Swift can call into C; in order to pass things to C, you're going to need to know the concrete type to match the calling convention of C. You might be better served with overloads of `doWithCType(cValue:)` (e.g. one for `Int`, one for `Double`, etc.) rather than a generic function.

Comment: So the idea is to define a struct in C, then pass the struct to ring buffer in C.  The generic in swift is used to define the type that the queue will accept in the swift layer to avoid all the unsafe casting.  Ultimately it’s meant as a convenience.

Comment: To clarify, I just used a generic function for brevity, really it would be a generic class.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920260/require-associatedtype-to-be-representable-in-a-conventionc-block

Answer (score 5):

Is `Swift.CVarArg` what you need?  It is for types that can be passed through C's `va_list` mechanism for varargs.

There is also `CVaListPointer`, which is equivalent to `va_list *`.  That appears in the arguments to `String(format:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cvararg
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cvalistpointer

Comment: Swift.CVarArg is actually what I was trying to cast to that caused the crash.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think if you want to pass structs between C and Swift you're going to end up with `UnsafeMutablePointer<Hodor>` or `COpaquePointer` in your API.  c.f. https://modocache.io/swift-and-c.

Comment: I'm going to end up casting to void* in the end, but I'm hoping to contain that casting in one function in a generic. The idea is to create a Swift interface to a C message queue. C can't use swift memory so I was hoping that there was a "C type" constraint.  Otherwise It'll come down to relying on documentation to enforce the C types.